# Silverlight / Java Applet equivalent?

Tags: java, c#, silverlight, npapi

My society was hit in the face with the NPAPI deprecation in the google browser.

We were using Silverlight for a long time and we are curently looking for any replacement solution.

What was good about applets and silverlight was the easiness for the applications to access the file system and get the rights to automatically save anything into the computer.

Beside it was compatible with the major OS and almost all Browsers, which was a great thing for our customers.

But chrome decided that NPAPI causes too much security problem, and they will remove it by september.

I'm looking for a simple way to provide access, at least to the file system of the customer.
asp.NET gives us anything we need, on the server side, but it can't do a thing on the client side. With silverlight we were able to use the clipboard,save multiples files on specific directory, send mails from the client etc.

I thought about making our own plugin on several OS, but that would be a lot of work. So i was wondering if there were a simple compatible solution that  already exists.

Comment: @fte, why not to post your comment as an answer?

Comment: Whichever answer you settle for, if it isn't natively supported by the browser, there's a big chance that it will be obsolete within the next year or two. Browser plugins like flash, Silverlight and javafx are seriously uncool. If you need more access to the client, write an application instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a FireBreath2 plugin to provide this functionality -- FireBreath2 will work on chrome w/ native messaging, and the functionality you describe shouldn't be too hard to do cross-platform.  Keep in mind that you've got some serious security risks to protect against, though.

FireBreath2 as of this writing isn't quite production ready, but it's pretty close. ActiveX support isn't complete yet, but it shouldn't take that much work to finish it.  It would require a good understanding of C++ and a willingness to help with the project since it's not 100% ready for prime time yet.

Comment: Please re-read my response; you seem to have missed a critical sentence, and it's the first one. FireBreath2 supports chrome w/ native messaging.